# Expected value of a fair dice

Tags: probability, expected-value

While calculating the expected value of a fair die we get $E=\left(1\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(2\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(3\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(4\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(5\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(6\cdot\frac{1}{6}\right)=3.5$. Does that mean the expected value that i will get from the die is 3.5?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. What's the question?

Comment: Yes. Which shows why "expected value" is not great terminology, considering that the expected value in this case will never be rolled. :-D

Comment: Well,  half the values are smaller and half the values are larger. @Bungo So it's intuitive in that sense. And two dice will give expected sum $7$ etc. Use the name "first moment" of the distribution to avoid the confusion..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Understood, I was being facetious. It's the expected value you will see *on average* if you roll a lot of dice (frequentist interpretation).

Comment: @Bungo I agree "long term average" is a better intuition builder than "expected value".

Answer (score 1):

Yes the expected value is $3.5$

It makes sense since the expected value is $E[X]$, which is the population **mean**. In this perfect theoretical experiment, you are taking the average of the dice results and dividing it by the number of rolls. The result does not necessarily have to be previously obtained in the experiment, nor even possible to obtain.